# How to detect if any of QML editable items in the root Item were edited?

Tags: qt, qml

I have an item of some type that consists of several QML editing controls:

```
Column {
   id: inputItem

   SpinBox {
   }
   TextInput {
   }
   ComboBox {
   }
   Button {
     id: enableMeButton   // this needs to be enabled if
     text: "Apply"        // anything was changed above
     enabled: false
   }
}
```

This item [Column as example] can be potentially inserted to some list view as "polymorphic" editing item so that we don't know beforehand what edit fields to handle (say we would want to move Apply outside). Or we want to use a common type with Apply to develop different editing delegates (which is the story here).

How can we detect that any of the data handled in this form was changed? Is there a generic way to do so or there is some trick to accomplish it?

Comment: Even though I don't like the idea, I'll notice that every editable control has some kind of `onChanged` event, for example [SpinBox.valueModified()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html#valueModified-signal) so you can trigger on it.

Comment: @folibis Precisely my point: want something like an "edit hook" handler here and not individual handlers setting the flag "data was changed".

Comment: wrap each control with your own module and have unified signals that emit when there's a change. You can also create a generic container that can bundle your new controls and itself emits a signal when any of its children emits that signal.

Comment: @bardao Thanks, I need to develop some solution based on your proposal to cover this obvious QML/QtQuick deficiency.

Comment: I'd call it flexibility :)